# How to combine two queries in SQL in search Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php page that is submitted a search string which is separated by commas. I have to search the database to check if the search terms are first names or last names, as well as if they match any of the interests/skills/hobbies in my interest/skill/hobby tables.

After I explode the string by ", " I first make the query to search for names which is

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users 
WHERE FirstName = 'term1' 
OR FirstName = 'term2' 
OR LastName = 'term1' 
OR LastName = 'term2'.
```

Then the query for searching by interests skills and hobbies and the users that have those tags is this

```
SELECT user_id from (
   (SELECT * 
    from UserInterests 
    WHERE interest_id = interestid1 
    OR interest_id = interestid2
    )
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT * 
    from UserSkills 
    WHERE skill_id = skillid1 
    OR skill_id = skillid2
    )
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT * 
    from UserHobbies 
    WHERE hobby_id = hobbyid1 
    OR hobby_id = hobbyid2
    )
) a 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

What I want to do is be able to search something like John, Rockclimbing, Dancing. Then the user who matches the most of those terms would be shown first.

I tried combining the two in many different ways some of which don't even error, but I don't get any results in my ui.

UserInterests/UserSkills/UserHobbies are just two column tables with user_id and interest/skill/hobby_id

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: My personal opinion is that this is a new user and he clearly put forth effort to construct this question, which is very clear to me, and being downvoted immediately after joining against expectation is not the right move. Also giving no context and only providing a link seems "not nice". If I knew how to answer the question, I would, but this seems like something more complex that there may be a library or package that could help.

Comment: What is *interestid1-2*, *skillid1-2*, *hobbyid1-2*? Are these the same as *term1-2*?

Comment: You can use FIND_IN_SET, first param should be the column, and the second is the string with commas.
Just join the tables and do the find_in_set.
```SQL
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('john','John, Rockclimbing, Dancing'); //will return 1
```
No need to explode the string by commas.